# Orthonormal basis for a complex vector space with countable vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space with a positive definite hermitian inner prod-
uct. $V$ has a countable basis. Can the gram schmidt process be used to get an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Yes, it can be used.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Do we always get a orthonormal basis if dimension of vector is countable? How does the proof go?

Comment: Each $e_k$ is defined only in terms of the basis vectors $v_i$ for $i < k$. So everything is finite. Each new $e_k$ is orthgonal to those defined before it. Those defined after are each chosen to be orthogonal to it, so in the end, they are all orthogonal. It is only when the basis is not countable that things fail.